# SQL: Returning date spans with gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I work for a health insurance company, and am trying to create a query which outputs eligibility spans for members.  The source table lists historical dates for all months a member is eligible for, once per month.  For example, if member 55555 is eligible from 01/15/2018-05/15/2018, there will be five entries.

This would be solveable easily (with a min and max) if it weren't for gaps in eligibility, so that makes it trickier.  Ideally, I would like a separate row for each member with their start and end date of eligibility.  So if the prior member had an eligibilty span which picked back up in July and went until August, there should be two rows returned:

```
Member_Nbr    Start_Date    End_Date
55555         01/15/2018    05/15/2018
55555         07/15/2018    08/15/2018


----------Sample Dataset:

create table #gaps (member_nbr varchar(5),membership_date date)
insert into #gaps(member_nbr,membership_date)
values ('55555','01/15/2018'),('55555','02/15/2018'),('55555','03/15/2018'), 
('55555','04/15/2018'),('55555','05/15/2018'),('55555','07/15/2018'), 
('55555','08/15/2018')

----------Without Gaps
select member_nbr,min(membership_date),max(membership_date)
from #gaps
group by member_nbr
order by member_nbr

----------With Gaps (desired output)
```

Is there a way to bring back eligibility dates in the desired way?

Thanks

Billy

Comment: What happens if Start_Date varies by day? It is very easy to assume that the 15th day of any month is important here. Why the 15th and not the 1st or the last day of each month?

Comment: This is a challenging piece of work until you understand what you are really trying to do here. Fortunately Jeff Moden has a great article discussing grouping islands of contiguous dates. You just need to modify this so that the contiguous dates are months instead of days. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/

Comment: Google `SQL gaps and islands problem`.. there will be lots of examples.

Comment: where is this data store ? "So if the prior member had an eligibilty span which picked back up in July and went until August, there should be two rows returned..." Give 2 example in Gaps table with expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a particularly hard problem.  Here is a pretty simple solution:

```
select member_nbr, min(membership_date), max(membership_date)
from (select g.*, row_number() over (partition by member_nbr order by membership_date) as seqnum
      from gaps g
     ) g
group by member_nbr, dateadd(month, - seqnum, membership_date);
```

along with a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cd60016c8c4f8fd7197f585085013f65).

The idea is pretty simple.  If you have a dates and subtract a sequence of numbers of months, then the result is constant for a sequence of adjacent months.  So:

```
2018-02-15   1    2018-01-15
2018-03-15   2    2018-01-15
2018-04-15   3    2018-01-15
2018-07-15   4    2018-03-15
2018-08-15   5    2018-03-15
2018-11-15   6    2018-05-15
```

The last column is used for aggregation.

Having dates that are not all on the 15th causes a problem.  That is easily fixed using a function such as `eomonth()`.